# Oracle's Merge v. Select->Update/Insert

Tags: oracle, performance, merge

What is the faster statement? A [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) or Select->Update/Insert depending on if it returns a value?

I'm trying to optimize a database, but I haven't found any speed tests comparing the two.

I found the MERGE command through a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936882/how-to-make-my-oracle-update-insert-action-through-java-faster)

Answer (score 7):

A `MERGE` would be more efficient since you're only executing the query once.  Even better would be to do a set-based `MERGE` rather than doing a bunch of single-row `MERGE` statements which is what I'm assuming you'd be implementing given the alternative of doing a `SELECT` to see if the row exists.

Rather than doing a `SELECT` and then determining whether to do an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`, you would be better off doing the `UPDATE`, checking to see if you updated 0 rows or not, and then doing the `INSERT` if your `UPDATE` didn't affect any rows.  That way, source rows that require an `UPDATE` would be a bit more efficient and rows that require an `INSERT` would be essentially just as fast as if you had done a `SELECT` and `INSERT`.  This approach is still going to be slower than a `MERGE`, but it's better than doing the extra `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Merge is not working for CLOB. it is working only for small string values.
In the below sql : eai_msg, msg_req_text, msg_req_rply are all CLOB.

If I pass data like "something", it works.

It is not working for input of 1200+ char:

```
"merge into some_table  msg using (select 1 from DUAL) d "
      + "on (msg.corr_id= :correlationId) "
      + "when matched then "
      + "update set  msg.rptg_id = :rptgId, "
      + "eai_rcvd_date = :receivedDate, "
      + "msg.eai_msg_text = :msgText, "
      + "msg.msg_req_text = :request, "
      + "msg.msg_rply_text = :reply, "
      + "msg.eai_svc_name = :serviceName, "
      + "msg.eqmt_cnt = :eqmtCount "
      + "when not matched then "
      + "insert (RPTG_ID, EAI_RCVD_DATE, EAI_MSG_TEXT, MSG_REQ_TEXT, MSG_RPLY_TEXT, EAI_SVC_NAME, EQMT_CNT, CORR_ID,MSG_KEY) "
      + "values (:rptgId, :receivedDate, :msgText, :request,:reply,:serviceName, :eqmtCount, :correlationId,:msgKey)"
```

here is my save method in dao

```
  public int saveEaiData(final SaveOriginalEAIRequestDto saveOriginalEaiDto) {
    NCDateTime eaiReceivedDateTime = saveOriginalEaiDto.getEaiReceivedDateTime();
    MapSqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    paramMap.addValue("msgKey", sequence.nextLongValue());
    paramMap.addValue("rptgId", saveOriginalEaiDto.getReportingId());
    if (eaiReceivedDateTime != null) {
      paramMap.addValue("receivedDate", eaiReceivedDateTime.getCalendarUTC());
    } else {
      paramMap.addValue("receivedDate", null);
    }
    paramMap.addValue("msgText", saveOriginalEaiDto.getEaiText(), Types.CLOB);
    paramMap.addValue("request", saveOriginalEaiDto.getRequestText(), Types.CLOB);
    paramMap.addValue("reply", saveOriginalEaiDto.getReplyText(), Types.CLOB);
    paramMap.addValue("serviceName", saveOriginalEaiDto.getEaiServiceName());
    paramMap.addValue("eqmtCount", saveOriginalEaiDto.getEquipmentCount());
    paramMap.addValue("correlationId", saveOriginalEaiDto.getCorrelationId());
    try {
      return getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update(MERGE_ORIGINAL_EAI_MSG_RECEIVED, paramMap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Exception occured in saveEaiData" + e);
    }
  }
```